# How to change the keys/first row in this CSV library import Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, import

```
class CSVReader {

    var $fields;            /** columns names retrieved after parsing */ 
    var $separator = ';';    /** separator used to explode each line */
    var $enclosure = '"';    /** enclosure used to decorate each field */

    var $max_row_size = 4096;    /** maximum row size to be used for decoding */

    function parse_file($p_Filepath) {

        $file = fopen($p_Filepath, 'r');
        $this->fields = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure);
        $keys_values = explode(',',$this->fields[0]);

        $content    =   array();
        $keys   =   $this->escape_string($keys_values);

        $i  =   1;
        while( ($row = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure)) != false ) {            
            if( $row != null ) { // skip empty lines
                $values =   explode(',',$row[0]);
                if(count($keys) == count($values)){
                    $arr    =   array();
                    $new_values =   array();
                    $new_values =   $this->escape_string($values);
                    for($j=0;$j<count($keys);$j++){
                        if($keys[$j] != ""){
                            $arr[$keys[$j]] =   $new_values[$j];
                        }
                    }

                    $content[$i]=   $arr;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($file);
        return $content;
    }

    function escape_string($data){
        $result =   array();
        foreach($data as $row){
            $result[]   =   str_replace('"', '',$row);
        }
        return $result;
    }   
}
```

In this is the code of the library for importing csv files to sql is the key is in the first row. I want to remove the first row keys in csv file and add it to this code.

Fields in first row of csv that I want to be in the already in the code:

```
$fields = array(        '0'     => 'model',
                        '1'     => 'serial_num' ,
                        '2'     => 'client_name',
                        '3'     => 'end_user',
                        '4'     => 'trends_warranty_start',
                        '5'     => 'trends_warranty_end',
                        '6'     => 'trends_warranty_period',
                        '7'     => 'client_contract_no',
                        '8'     => 'vendor',
                        '9'     => 'support_coverage',
                        '10'    => 'sla',
                        '11'    => 'service_contract_num',
                        '12'    => 'support_coverage_start',
                        '13'    => 'support_coverage_end',
                        '14'    => 'support_coverage_period',
                        '15'    => 'trends_po',
                        '16'    => 'supplier_so');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making change in the code you can simply add these columns in the first row of csv file. And the will be available in the code.

```
"serial_num" ,"client_name","end_user","trends_warranty_start","trends_warranty_end","trends_warranty_period","client_contract_no","vendor","support_coverage","sla","service_contract_num","support_coverage_start","support_coverage_end","support_coverage_period","trends_po","supplier_so"
```

The other possibel scanrio is that when you get csv result add column names in the result array like this

```
$result =   $this->csvreader->parse_file('Test.csv');

$columns    =    array(
                    'model',
                    'serial_num' ,
                    'client_name',
                    'end_user',
                    'trends_warranty_start',
                    'trends_warranty_end',
                    'trends_warranty_period',
                    'client_contract_no',
                    'vendor',
                    'support_coverage',
                    'sla',
                    'service_contract_num',
                    'support_coverage_start',
                    'support_coverage_end',
                    'support_coverage_period',
                    'trends_po',
                    'supplier_so'
);

$resultWithColumns  =   array_unshift($result , $columns);
```

And now you have column names in the result array.

Comment: where should I put the $resultWithColumns? in the class CSVreader?

Comment: you don't have to do any change in csvreader. This should be done in your controller

Comment: can i ask again sir what if the Date in my csv file is "JAN. 6, 2014" how do i change it to "2014-01-06" in your code? and again thanks for this import csv library code

Comment: Can you post your csv result in print_r($resultWithColumns);

Comment: you can use php function date() to convert it to the desired format